# Haskell dividing num

Tags: haskell, types, division, typeclass

I'm having an issue I want to learn more about, and how to avoid. I've got this code

```
len :: (Num r ) => [a] -> r
len [] = 0
len xs = 1 + len ( tail xs )

avg :: (Num t) => [t] -> Double
avg xs = ( sum xs ) / ( len xs )
```

Which renders the following error

```
len.hs:6:9:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' against inferred type `t'
      `t' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `avg' at len.hs:5:12
    In the expression: (sum xs) / (len xs)
    In the definition of `avg': avg xs = (sum xs) / (len xs)
```

Now, I know this error (thanks to irc.freenode.net#haskell) is a result of the division function

```
(/) :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
```

However, I don't know what to do. My `avg` function signature should have nothing to do with the division opperators quirks (requiring `Fractional` typeclass). So, I'm left thinking the right way to overcome this is by casting to a type that impliments they `Fractional` typeclass but I have no idea how, or even if this is right? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My `avg` function signature should have nothing to do with the division operator's quirks

Why is that? If you want to compute the average of a bunch of Integers, you'll have to divide at some point, so you'll have to convert them from Integers to the division-supporting type of your choice. A close look at the `Num` class (`:i Num` in ghci) reveals one problem with the type of `avg`: `Num` doesn't have enough methods — basically enough to add, multiply, and subtract. There's no guarantee that the number I give to `avg` can be converted to a `Double` at all.

If you enter an untyped function to compute an average, Haskell responds with the most generic type possible:

```
Prelude List> :type \x -> sum x / genericLength x
\x -> sum x / genericLength x :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
```

So that's the correct type of `avg`.

You might notice that `avg [1,2,3 :: Integer]` gives a type error. You can get around that by passing the argument to `toRational` or `fromIntegral` first, which use the `Real` and `Integral` instances for `Integer`, respectively.

---

Regarding the expression `sum [1,2,3] / len [1,2,3]`: It's true that a literal number like `1` has the type of `Num a => a`, which calls `fromInteger` on whatever type it turns out to be, but an expression like `1/2` has a more specific type of `Fractional a => a`, which you can see if you ask for the type of that expression instead of printing it out.

Something that might be helpful is `:set -Wall` in ghci, which turns on lots of warnings whenever a default type is chosen for you, giving a clue that the most generic type might no longer be correct.

Comment: I've chosen this as the answer, (definitely gives the most effort) but I'd like a quick follow up with a resource of where I can find what the prelude has for types, and type-classes regarding number-like types. What types of integers am i precluding by requiring the inputs be apart of Fractional? I've never seen a type apart of this typeclass prior to doing `:t (/) and I'd like to know more about how it works. And, things magically join the class for the division

Comment: All those declarations are in the Prelude. Online reference here: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.2/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html

Comment: I once saw a directed acyclic graph showing the numeric type class hierarchy, but I can't find it now. Here's a gentle introduction: (http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html). You can tell ghci to give you more info by using `:i (/)`, or :i on a type or class.

Answer (score 5):

You're overly constraining the type of avg. Use the more general version, avg ::  (Fractional a) => [a] -> a

Comment: my question would be, why is the stuff returned by `len` is part of the member to the `Fractional` typeclass, `:t sum [1,2,3]` and `:t len [1,2,3]`  both show the result is only part of the `Num` typeclass. I'm confused how a function that requires its arguments to be apart of the `Fractional` typeclass can even be applied here.

Comment: EvanCarroll: The `Num` typeclass does not provide fractional division, but the `Fractional` typeclass does.  Since `avg` uses `/` in its top-level calculation the type signature must reflect that.  When you make this change the compiler knows to use floating point math in `sum` and `len`.

Answer (score 1):

hhm the really problem is if it is an integral type you want to cast to a fractional type, but if it is an fractional type you want to leave it alone.

Try this

```
fromRational ((sum xs) % (leng xs))
```

Comment: mauke in irc `17:14 < mauke> EvanCarroll: % requires integers` talking to him is too difficult., and I'd rather not ask him what he means by it. `:t (%)` isn't showing anything useful either.

Comment: @Evan: upshaw's code uses http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Ratio.html -- It only works if the list elements are integers.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem. This best I've managed to do is have two functions for averaging: one for integrals and one for fractionals:

```
avgInt :: (Integral i, Fractional f) => [i] -> f
avgInt xs = fromIntegral (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs)

avgFrac :: (Fractional f) => [f] -> f
avgFrac xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```