# Haskell: Using map in function composition

Tags: haskell, syntax, dictionary, function-composition

I am relatively new to Haskell so apologies if my question sounds stupid. I have been trying to understand how function composition works and I have come across a problem that I was wondering someone could help me with. I am using map in a function composition in the following two scenarios:

- `map (*2) . filter even [1,2,3,4]`
- `map (*2) . zipWith max [1,2] [4,5]`

Although both the filter and zipWith functions return a list, only the first composition works while the second composition throws the below error:

```
"Couldn't match expected type '[Int] -> [Int]' with actual type '[c0]'
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834626/haskell-dot-operator) help? (Especially [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2834661/1256624))

Comment: The first one actually produces the output `Couldn't match expected type a0 -> [b0]' with actual type [a1]'`

Answer (score 19):

Recall the type of `(.)`.

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

It takes three arguments: two functions and an initial value, and returns the result of the two functions composed.

Now, application of a function to its arguments binds tighter than the `(.)` operator.
So your expression:

```
map (*2) . filter even [1,2,3,4]
```

is parsed as:

```
(.) (map (*2)) (filter even [1,2,3,4])
```

now, the first argument, `map (*2)` is ok. It has type `(b -> c)`, where `b` and `c` is `Num a => [a]`. However, the second argument is a single list:

```
Prelude> :t filter even [1,2,3,4]
filter even [1,2,3,4] :: Integral a => [a]
```

and so the type checker will complain that you're passing a `[a]` as an argument when the `(.)` function needs a function.

And that's what we see:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> [b0]' with actual type `[a1]'
In the return type of a call of `filter'
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `filter even [1, 2, 3, 4]'
In the expression: map (* 2) . filter even [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So...  parenthesization!

Either use   the `$` operator to add a parenthesis:

```
map (*2) . filter even $ [1,2,3,4]
```

or use explicit parens, removing the composition of two functions

```
map (*2) (filter even [1,2,3,4])
```

or even:

```
(map (*2) . filter even) [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: I know that OP asked specifically about function composition, but this example is really best suited to straight up `$`, _i.e._, `map (*2) $ filter even [1,2,3,4]`.

Answer (score 5):

The result of `zipWith max [1,2] [4,5]` is a list, not a function.  The (.) operator requires a function as its right operand. Hence the error on your second line.  Probably what you want is

```
map (*2) (zipWith max [1,2] [4,5])
```

Your first example does not compile on WinHugs (Hugs mode); it has the same error.  The following will work

```
(map (*2) . filter even) [1,2,3,4]
```

as it composes two functions and applies the resulting function to an argument.

Answer (score 5):

The following forms are valid:

```
map (* 2) $ filter even [1, 2, 3, 4]
(map (* 2) . filter even) [1, 2, 3, 4]
map (* 2) $ zipWith max [1, 2] [4, 5]
(\xs -> map (* 2) . zipWith max xs) [1, 2] [4, 5]
```

but not the following:

```
map (* 2) . filter even [1, 2, 3, 4]
map (* 2) . zipWith max [1, 2] [4, 5]
(map (* 2) . zipWith max) [1, 2] [4, 5]
```

Why is that so? Well, take for example

```
map (* 2) . zipWith max [1, 2] [4, 5]
```

it is the same as

```
(map (* 2)) . (((zipWith max) [1, 2]) [4, 5])
```

`(map (* 2))` has type `[Int] -> [Int]` (assuming defaulting for `Int`), `(((zipWith max) [1, 2]) [4, 5])` has type `[Int]` and `(.)` has type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` or `([Int] -> [Int]) -> ([Int] -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> [Int]` in this non-polymorphic case, so this is ill-typed. On the other hand `($)` has type `(a -> b) -> a -> b`, or `([Int] -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> [Int]` in this non-polymorphic case, so this:

```
(map (* 2)) $ (((zipWith max) [1, 2]) [4, 5])
```

is well-typed.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the low precedence of `(.)`, Haskell parses

```
map (*2) . filter even [1,2,3,4]
```

as

```
map (*2) . (filter even [1,2,3,4])
```

i.e. compose `map (*2)` (a function) with the result of `filter even [1,2,3,4]` (a list), which makes no sense, and is a type error.

You can fix this using @Theodore's suggestions, or by using `($)`:

```
map (*2) . filter even $ [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the type of map it is: `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`

So, it takes a function of a into b and then a list of a and returns a list of b. Right?

Now, you already provide a function of a into b by passing the parameter `(*2)`. So, your partially applied map function end up being: `[Integer] -> [Integer]` meaning that you will receive a list of integers and return a list of integers.

Up to this point, you could compose (.) a function that has the same signature. If you check what is the type of `filter even` you would see that it is: `[Integer] -> [Integer]`, as such a valid candidate for composition here.

This composition then, does not alter the final signature of the function, if you check the type of: `map (*2) . filter even` it is `[Integer] -> [Integer]`

This would not be the case of the `map (*2) . zipWith max [1,2] [4,5]` because the `zipWith max` does not have the same signature as the one expected by `map (*2)`.