# Lazy Evaluation - Space Leak

Tags: haskell

[Thinking Functionally with Haskell](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/computer-science/programming-languages-and-applied-logic/thinking-functionally-haskell) provides the following code for calculating the **mean** of a list of **Float**'s.

```
mean :: [Float] -> Float
mean [] = 0
mean xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

Prof. Richard Bird comments:

> Now we are ready to see what is really wrong with mean: it has a space leak. Evaluating `mean [1..1000]` will cause the list to be expanded and retained in memory after summing because there is a second pointer to it, namely in the computation of its length.

If I understand this text correctly, he's saying that, if there was no pointer to `xs` in the length computation, then the `xs` memory could've been freed **after** calculating the `sum`?

My confusion is - if the `xs` is already in memory, isn't the `length` function simply going to use the same memory that's already being taken up?

I don't understand the space leak here.

Comment: Hmm, "leak" to me seems a little odd... But definitely one thing to note: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2380437/667648

sum xs is calculated, then length xs is calculated, making two passes through instead of one.

Comment: Not really related to the question but if you're ever going to write a mean function, please please please have it return a `Maybe`. There's no way of distinguishing a real 0 from a fake one here.

Comment: A Haskell koan: Computing `sum xs` is not a problem. Computing `length xs` is not a problem. Computing `sum xs / length xs` is a problem.

Comment: @DanielWagner I fail to understand this. Given that `sum` is defined lazily in terms of `foldl` won't it cause space leak? Giving `sum [1..10000000]` in my laptop increases my laptop's memory usage like anything. Whereas, `mysum = foldl' (+) 0` runs on constant memory space ?

Comment: @Sibi That is indeed an unfortunate historical detail. But it really detracts from the beauty of the koan to substitute `foldl' (+) 0` for `sum` everywhere while adding little of interest to the novice, don't you agree? =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `sum` function does not need to keep the entire list in memory; it can look at an element at a time then forget it as it moves to the next element.

Because Haskell has lazy evaluation by default, if you have a function that creates a list, `sum` could consume it without the whole list ever being in memory (each time a new element is generated by the producing function, it would be consumed by `sum` then released).

The exact same thing happens with `length`.

On the other hand, the `mean` function feeds the list to both `sum` and `length`. So during the evaluation of `sum`, we need to keep the list in memory so it can be processed by `length` later.

[Update] to be clear, the list will be garbage collected eventually. The problem is that it stays longer than needed. In such a simple case it is not a problem, but in more complex functions that operate on infinite streams, this would most likely cause a memory leak.

Comment: `sum` is implemented lazily in Prelude. I think it will still keep the entire list in memory ?

Comment: Yes, because it's not `sum` that keeps the list in memory; it's `mean` which needs it for both `sum` then `length`.

Comment: It is a problem in this case, because that allocation is much more expensive than computing the list as a loop twice, as it would be if you inlined both occurrences

Comment: @FrédéricDumont, Sorry, I think I was not being clear. There can be two ways in which the entire list can be in memory: From the `xs` which is producing lazily and the lazy `foldl` operation which will expand the entire list with (+) operation on it. Bird is probably referring to first type of condition. Although, even using normal `sum` function will lead to a space leak.

Comment: @Sibi yes, clearly Bird is referring to the first type. And it boggles the mind that `sum` is still implemented with a non-strict accumulator, although it's possible that it's not a problem in practice when strictness analysis kicks in.

Answer (score 4):

Others have explained what the problem is. The cleanest solution is probably to use Gabriel Gonzalez's [foldl package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl). Specifically, you'll want to use

```hs
import qualified Control.Foldl as L
import Control.Foldl (Fold)
import Control.Applicative

meanFold :: Fractional n => Fold n (Maybe n)
meanFold = f <$> L.sum <*> L.genericLength where
  f _ 0 = Nothing
  f s l = Just (s/l)

mean :: (Fractional n, Foldable f) => f n -> Maybe n
mean = L.fold meanFold
```

Answer (score 3):

> if there was no pointer to `xs` in the `length` computation, then the `xs` memory could've been freed **after** calculating the `sum`?

No, you're missing the important aspect of lazy evaluation here. You're right that `length` will use the same memory as was allocated during the `sum` call, the memory in which we had expanded the whole list.

But the point here is that allocating memory for the whole list shouldn't be necessary at all. If there was no `length` computation but only the `sum`, then *memory could've been freed **during** calculating the `sum`*. Notice that the list `[1..1000]` is *lazily generated* only when it is consumed, so in fact the `mean [1..1000]` should run in constant space.

You might write the function like the following, to get an idea of how to avoid such a space leak:

```
import Control.Arrow

mean [] = 0
mean xs = uncurry (/) $ foldr (\x -> (x+) *** (1+)) (0, 0) xs

-- or more verbosely
mean xs = let (sum, len) = foldr (\x (s, l) -> (x+s, 1+l)) (0, 0)
          in sum / len
```

which *should* traverse `xs` only once. However, Haskell is damn lazy - and computes the first tuple components only when evaluating `sum` and the second ones only later for `len`. We need to [use some more tricks](https://wiki.haskell.org/Stack_overflow#Weak_Head_Normal_Form) to actually force the evaluation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Data.List

mean [] = 0
mean xs = uncurry (/) $ foldl' (\(!s, !l) x -> (x+s, 1+l)) (0,0) xs
```

which really runs in constant space, as you can confirm in ghci by using `:set +s`.

Answer (score 1):

The space leak is that the entire evaluated `xs` is held in memory for the `length` function. This is wasteful, as we aren't going to be using the actual values of the list after evaluating `sum`, nor do we need them all in memory at the same time, but Haskell doesn't know that.

A way to remove the space leak would be to recalculate the list each time:

```
sum [1..1000] / fromIntegral (length [1..1000])
```

Now the application can immediately start discarding values from the first list as it is evaluating `sum`, since it is not referenced anywhere else in the expression.

The same applies for `length`. The thunks it generates can be marked for deletion immediately, since nothing else could possibly want it evaluated further.

EDIT:

Implementation of `sum` in [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Data-List.html#sum):

```
sum l = sum' l 0
  where
    sum' []     a = a
    sum' (x:xs) a = sum' xs (a+x)
```

Comment: I think even a normal `sum` function would cause a space leak. `sum` is defined in the prelude as `foldl (+) 0`.

Comment: That approach wound not work to implement the `mean` function.