# Why it is impossible to divide Integer number in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

This code

```
(4 :: Integer) / 2
```

will lead to error:

```
  No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of ‘/’
    In the expression: (4 :: Integer) / 2
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = (4 :: Integer) / 2
```

Why?

I need to specify

```
fromIntegral(4 :: Integer) / 2
```

to get a result. But what if I need a real number and not `2.0`?

Comment: IMO, a more natural question would be “why is it possible to divide integer numbers in so many other programming languages?” seeing as most integers are not divisible by each other and _integer division_ is thus something quite markedly different from (fractional) division.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell types frustrating a simple 'average' function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376981/haskell-types-frustrating-a-simple-average-function)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because the `Integer` type has no `Fractional` instance.

The type for `(/)` is `Fractional a => a -> a -> a`. Consider what happens when `a = Integer`. You'd have `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`.  But `1/2` is **not** an integer, it's `0.5`. So the only way to fit the division operator would be to *round* the result. But there is *not* a single way to round, and the best choice depends on the application, hence it was decided to *not* provide that instance.

If you want to perform *integer division* use the [`div`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div) or [`quot`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:quot) functions (they use different rounding).
Otherwise convert to something that supports a well-defined division operation like `Rational` (this is what the `fromIntegral` is doing).

Comment: Is it possible to perform Integer Division with `Integer` instead of `Int`?

Comment: @MarkNeu The functions `div` and `quot` have type `Integral a => a -> a -> a`. `Integer` does have an `Integral` instance, hence yes.

Answer (score 7):

Because the division operator for integers has two results (quotient and remainder):

```
divMod :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
```

You can also use the `div` operator:

```
n `div` m
```

which returns only one component of the division result (the quotient), but that's not the same thing as `n / m`.  `/` is for types where the division operator has only one result which combines 'quotient' and 'remainder' in one fraction.

Equationally, if `` (q, r) = n `divMod` m ``, then

```
n = m * q + r
```

whereas if `q = x / y`, then

```
x = y * q
```

(up to the usual caveats about floating point numbers and approximations).

Substituting `div` for `/` breaks that relationship, because it throws away some of the information you need to reproduce `n`.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, the class `Fractional` contains all types which are capable of division. Indeed, this is how division is defined; accordingly, whenever Haskell encounters `/`, it looks for an instance of `Fractional` for the type being operated on. Because there is no instance of the class `Fractional` for `Integer`, Haskell does not have a definition for `/` on `Integer`.

Haskell has several subclasses of the `Num` class, and they are worth being familiar with in order to type your classes in the most appropriate way possible.