# Type error while deviding in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I am trying to write a function in Haskell to devide to Integers. Here is my Code:

```
div :: Int -> Int -> Double
div a b =a/b
```

However, when I try to complie it i always get the error:

```
baby.hs:20:10:
  Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’
  In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘a’
  In the expression: a / b

baby.hs:20:12:
  Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’
  In the second argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘b’
  In the expression: a / b
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: There's an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950600/why-it-is-impossible-to-divide-integer-number-in-haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `Int`s first, for example using `realToFrac`. Renaming `div` to `myDiv` to avoid a clash with prelude, the program

```
myDiv :: Int -> Int -> Double
myDiv a b = realToFrac a / realToFrac b

main = putStrLn $ show $ myDiv 5 2
```

outputs

```
2.5
```