# sum of multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000 in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types

The following works fine:

```
sdb n = sum [n,n*2..999]
main = print $ sdb 3 + sdb 5 - sdb 15
```

But it's not that efficient since it has to sum 999/n times each time sdb is called.
when I rewrote sdb:

```
sdb n = 
    let x = quot 999 n
    in n*x*(x+1)/2
```

and `runhaskell` the whole code, I got an entire page of error. Summing it up:

```
... No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
... No instance for (Integral a0) arising from a use of `sdb'
... No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of `-'
```

I added type declaration for sdb:

```
sdb :: Integer -> Integer
```

but I got another error:

```
No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of `/'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the expression: n * x * (x + 1) / 2
    In the expression: let x = quot 999 n in n * x * (x + 1) / 2
    In an equation for `sdb':
        sdb n = let x = quot 999 n in n * x * (x + 1) / 2
```

I don't get it.

1. What should I correct? Can you also explain why I got those errors?
   **SOLVED**: I changed `/` with `div`.
2. Is there a more idiomatic and/or concise way to write the same algorithm?

Comment: It's `Integer`. `Integral` is a type class.

Comment: thanks, corrected, but I still get an error

Comment: `/` in `n*x*(x+1)/2` is defined for only fractions. You may use `quot` or `div` instead.

Comment: I already did that when I rewrote sdb function

Comment: opps - sorry - nevermind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell types frustrating a simple 'average' function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376981/haskell-types-frustrating-a-simple-average-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
sum [x | x <- [1..999], x `mod` 3 == 0 || x `mod` 5 == 0]
```

**Edit**

For a small upper bound like `999` this would be a more idiomatic and concise way, but if a more general solution is required, above would be too slow. Here is a better approach, which similarly to the questions itself, uses "Gauss's trick" to sum numbers divisible by `n`:

```
sumOfMults :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> a
sumOfMults n1 n2 m = sdb n1 + sdb n2 - sdb (lcm n1 n2) where
  sdb n = let x = m `div` n
          in n * x * (x + 1) `div` 2
```

Comment: shorter, of course, but slower :/ and it's a different algorithm from mine.
I asked for a more idiomatic and/or concise way of writing the same algorithm because I'm new to Haskell and I want to learn the best syntax

Comment: It is more idiomatic and concise. Looking at this code it is extremely easy to see what is actually going on, it's almost like a specification of the problem itself (Sum all numbers from 1 to 999 that are divisible by 3 or 5). I do agree that it is slower, but that would only matter if you where working with upper bounds of much higher than `999`.

Comment: oh sure, but I put 999 just as an example. Sorry for not being clear!

Comment: @Pigna, in that case your solution was good. I added a little more general one, see the edit.