# Haskell Type Errors with division

Tags: haskell

I have the below simple program to find the average of a list. I know my error is related to the inference of types but I cannot correct it. Can I get a correction and a simple explanation for this?

```
average :: Float
average= uncurry (/) . sumlen

sumlen ::[Int]-> (Int,Int)
sumlen = foldl f (0,0)
         where f (s,n) x = (s+x,n+1)
```

The error is:

```
  • Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’
                      with actual type ‘[Int] -> Int’
   • Probable cause: ‘(.)’ is applied to too few arguments
          In the expression: uncurry (/) . sumlen
          In an equation for ‘average’: average = uncurry (/) . sumlen
```

Comment: The average of which list are you trying to find? Do you maybe want `average` to be a function, not a `Float`?

Comment: firstly: `average` is not a `Float`. It is a function `[Int] -> Float`. Also, you should explictly convert your `Int`s into `Float` when applying `(/)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell types frustrating a simple 'average' function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376981/haskell-types-frustrating-a-simple-average-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: Haskell is a strongly typed language.

You force the type of `sumlen` to be `[Int] -> (Int,Int)`.

The type of `(/)` is `Fractional a => a -> a -> a`.

Let us typecheck your function. First we will try to infer its type:

```
average = (uncurry (/)) . sumlen 
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c
(/) :: Fractional d => d -> d -> d
(.) :: (f -> g) -> (e -> f) -> e -> g
sumlen :: [Int] -> (Int,Int)
So:
e = [Int]
f = (Int,Int) = (a,b) = (d,d)
g = d = Int
average :: Fractional Int => [Int] -> Int
```

Now you tell Haskell that `average :: Float` and Haskell tells you that a float is not a function. This is your error.

If you remove the annotation then you will be told that there is no instance `Fractional Int`. This is because you can’t represent or reasonably approximate `1 / 2` as an `Int`.

How to fix this?

Step 0 is to not write down a type signature that is wrong (ie `average :: Float`)

One thing you could do is have a more general sumlen. Try `Num a => [a] -> (a,a)` instead. You could even have `(Num a, Num b) => [a] -> (a,b)`. Then you can have the sensible type `average :: Fractional a => [a] -> a`

Another thing you could do is convert from integers:

```
average xs = fromIntegral s / fromIntegral l where
  (s,l) = sumlen xs
```